# Firebase functions install failing due to auth

Tags: firebase, npm

I keep trying to npm install firebase functions.  I've done this many times before and this is the first time I am getting this issue.  The error is as follows:

```
PS C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\sultvueweb> npm install firebase firebase/functions       
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/firebase/functions.git     
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-28T22_58_26_800Z-debug.log
```

I can't seem to figure out where I need to update my credentials to make this work.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: try installing with sudo

Comment: Running on a windows machine currently, just needed admin prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was I didn't have an elevated command prompt in my text editor.  I tried it in an admin prompt and worked right away.  Not sure why it would have given the errors it did.